# Laravel: How to get associated table's columns in eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

**I have three Database Tables.**

```
CREATE TABLE `tblproject` (
  `ProjectID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectStatusID` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

CREATE TABLE `tblSkills` (
  `SkillID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Skill` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

CREATE TABLE `tblprojectSkills` (
  `ProjectSkillID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectID` int NOT NULL,
  `SkillID` int NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**In the above tables. `SkillID` is related in `tblSkills` and `tblprojectSkills`.
`ProjectID` is related in `Project` and `projectSkills` Table**

### **My project Model is below.**

```
class Project_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblproject";
    protected $primaryKey = "ProjectID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function ProjectSkills() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ProjectSkill_Model', 'ProjectID');
    }        
}
```

### **Database Query in laravel 5.1 is below.**

```
\App\Models\Project\Project_Model
::with('ProjectSkills')
->where('ProjectID', '=', $ProjectID)->first();
```

### **Question**

I can get the Skill ID, But, How can I get the Skill Name from Skill Table ?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the fields you want with a closure:

```
\App\Models\Project\Project_Model
::with('ProjectSkills' => function($q)
{
    $q->select('SkillID', 'Skill');
})
->where('ProjectID', '=', $ProjectID)->first();
```

Alternatively, you could add the fields you want directly in the relation of your model:

```
public function ProjectSkills() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ProjectSkill_Model', 'ProjectID')
                ->select('SkillID', 'Skill');
}
```

Comment: I got this error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'skill' in 'field list' (SQL: select `SkillID`, `skill` from `tblprojectskills` where `tblprojectskills`.`ProjectID` in (10))`

Comment: @PankajGarg : i see that probably you relation is a many-to-many through a pivot table, so the relation in your model should be: return `$this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\ProjectSkill_Model', 'tblprojectSkills', 'ProjectID', 'SkillID');` check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: `ProjectID` in `tblproject` is related with `ProjectID` in `tblprojectSkills` and `SkillID` in `tblSkill` is related with `SkillID` in `tblprojectSkills`

Comment: yes, `tblprojectSkills` is called a 'pivot table', as it's like a 'pivot' between the two other tables. They are used for many to many relationships. Check the link above to see how they work in Laravel

Comment: After changing it to `belongsToMany`, I got the below error. `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'tblprojectskill' (SQL: select `SkillID`, `tblskill`, `tblprojectskill`.`ProjectID` as `pivot_ProjectID`, `tblprojectskill`.`SkillID` as `pivot_SkillID` from `tblprojectskill` inner join `tblprojectskill` on `tblprojectskill`.`ProjectSkillID` = `tblprojectskill`.`SkillID` where `tblprojectskill`.`ProjectID` in (10))`

Comment: in the model class for the table `tblSkills`, have you set `$table = 'tblSkills'` ?